# Obtain list of actively used locales - Magento 2 CLI

Tags: magento2, cli

I know that with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB` I can generate the static content for the above two locales.

How can I look up which locales are actively being used by a store (Imagine someone gave you ssh logins to a store you don't know which locales are used)?

So effectively I am looking for `command XXX` which should produce `en_US en_GB` (ideally something that is supported on 2.1)

Answer (score 2):

Provided the locales have been previously deployed this works:
`ls pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/`
but is not guaranteed to be there/complete and does not account for the frontend potentially having themes and different locales for each.

EDIT: slightly better option:

```
user@host:/var/www$ find pub/static -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d
pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/ca_ES
pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US
pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/ca_ES
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/de_DE
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/ca_ES
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US
```

Answer (score 2):

from your root folder, run this command:

```
php ./bin/magento config:show general/locale/code
```

that should show you what locale has been configured across your websites/ store view

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it's a good option for M2.2+ but is not included in M2.1. Since the command only outputs the default scope I would now need a command to list all the scope codes.

Comment: One unusual case I think it would miss is, if admin users have selected a locale for their account which is not used in the frontend.

Comment: Oh right, I wasn't aware the command is not available on 2.1. But hopefully this helps a bit if you ever run into this on post 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this reliably in Magento 2.1 onwards with [GetPageSpeed n98-magerun2 commands](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/n98-magerun2-module-getpagespeed), e.g.:

```
n98-magerun2 deploy:locale:active
#> en_US en_GB
```